# Jeromq on android : No virtual method clear()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer

Tags: java, android, zeromq, jeromq

I'm trying to use jeromq for an android project. I need to connect to another dealer device. Here is my code :

```
ZContext zcontext = new ZContext(1);
ZMQ.Socket zsocket = zcontext.createSocket(ZMQ.DEALER);
String identity = "S61_phone";
zsocket.setIdentity(identity.getBytes(ZMQ.CHARSET));
zsocket.connect("tcp://my_other_device_ip_and_port_here");
zsocket.send("test",0);
```

At the connect call, an error occurs :

> 2019-09-26 16:59:53.033 18347-18379/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: Thread-4 Process: com.flir.flironeexampleapplication, PID: 18347 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method clear()Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer; in class Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.nio.ByteBuffer' appears in /system/framework/core-oj.jar)
>     at zmq.Signaler.send(Signaler.java:97)
>     at zmq.Mailbox.send(Mailbox.java:71) at
>     zmq.Ctx.sendCommand(Ctx.java:517) at
>     zmq.ZObject.sendCommand(ZObject.java:382) at
>     zmq.ZObject.sendPlug(ZObject.java:185) at
>     zmq.ZObject.sendPlug(ZObject.java:175) at
>     zmq.Own.launchChild(Own.java:115) at
>     zmq.SocketBase.addEndpoint(SocketBase.java:590) at
>     zmq.SocketBase.connect(SocketBase.java:582) at
>     org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.connect(ZMQ.java:2531) at
>     com.flir.flironeexampleapplication.GLPreviewActivity.onDeviceConnected(GLPreviewActivity.java:115)
>     at com.flir.flironesdk.EmbeddedDevice$4.run(EmbeddedDevice.java:512)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

My environment :

- jeromq 0.5.2
- target device executing the code is Android 8.1 (Oreo)
- Compiling in Android Studio with JDK 1.8.0_66 / ndk r10e

Any idea of what is the problem ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Something wrong with your installation. The method definitely exists.

Answer (score 7):

I found an explanation and a workaround [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2559)

> Java 9 introduces overridden methods with covariant return types for the following methods in java.nio.ByteBuffer that are used by the driver.
>
> - position
> - limit
> - flip
> - clear
>
> In Java 9 they all now return a ByteBuffer , whereas the methods they override return Buffer, resulting in exceptions like this when executing on Java 8 and lower.
>
> This is because the generated byte code includes the static return type of the method, >which is not found on Java 8 and lower because the overloaded methods with covariant >return types don't exist.
>
> **The solution is to cast ByteBuffer instances to Buffer before calling the method.**